# Project Server Capabilities in SharePoint 2016

Tags: service-application, 2016

Want to get the Project Server Capabilities/features in SharePoint 2016 version.
I read and gone through MVP Vlad Catrinescu's video in channel9 [Whats-New-in-SP-2016](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/vladcatrinescu/Whats-new-in-SharePoint-2016-for-IT-Pros)
 about the new features of SP 2016 and he mentioned about the project server as a new service application in SP 2016.Can anyone throw more light on this?

If its a service application,how to configure and set up the Project Server functionality -like uploading a mpp file and generate a task file , with sub tasks with reminders, due date etc.

Also how to integrate it with the SP D workflows,OOTB workflows task list with the project level tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big change is, MSFT moved project server from separate installation to as run as a service application. SharePoint MSI contains all the required bits in it. I think this shift give Projects more options and better integration with SharePoint.

There is no resource available for project server 2016 with new features but couple of as listed on MSDN etc.

- single database for all Project Web App instance.
- [Resource Engagements](https://blogs.office.com/2015/06/19/resource-engagements-coming-soon-to-project-2016/)
- Custom field limits
- [Mutilple timeline](http://www.wellingtone.co.uk/microsoft-project-server-2016-new-features/)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631142(v=office.16).aspx

You can also read this what deprecated or removed? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt422816(v=office.16).aspx